# Bending a wire to form circle and ellipse

Tags: opengl, math, graphics, geometry

I have given N points on a straight line, these are lets say- (x1,y1) , (x2, y2), .... (xn, yn) , these points represent a wire in 3D. I want this wire to bend to form shape of circle and ellipse. So these points will map to points on circle and ellipse. Tell about some mapping technique that maps points on straight line onto points on circle and ellipse.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the line points to scalar parametric coordinates `0 <= t <= 1`.

Multiply the `t` coordinates by `2*pi` (giving `theta`) and plug them into the parametric circle equation:

```
x = cos( theta )
y = sin( theta )
```

Example:

Given 4 points (0,0), (1,1), (5,5), and (10,10) convert to parametric coordinates like so:

```
length = | (10,10) - (0,0) | = sqrt( 10^2 + 10^2 ) = sqrt( 200 )
t0 = 0.0 = | (0,0) - (0,0) |   / length = 0
t1 = 0.1 = | (1,1) - (0,0) |   / length = sqrt( 2 ) / length
t2 = 0.5 = | (5,5) - (0,0) |   / length = sqrt( 50 ) / length
t3 = 1.0 = | (10,10) - (0,0) | / length = sqrt( 200 ) / length

p0.x = cos( t0 * 2 * pi ) = 1
p0.y = sin( t0 * 2 * pi ) = 0
p1.x = cos( t1 * 2 * pi ) = 0.80901699437
p1.y = sin( t1 * 2 * pi ) = 0.58778525229
...
```